# graphs similarity measure implementation

Tags: matlab, graph, distance, similarity

I'm trying to find an appropriate similarity measure between two graphs. In fact, node label in my application are matrix (each row represent a particular feature histogram) and edge label are 0/1 (edge or no-edge between linked vertices).

I read that graph edit distance is used for attributed graphs which I think is the case in my work. So, I tried to implement it, but I found several difficulties like the cost function definition in my case and the computational cost.

So, is there a programming library or codes, perferably on MATLAB,  that computes graph edit distances, or, once again, any other graph similarity measures, between two graphs?